Can we express binary functions in terms of differential equations with xor as differential operator?
Differential equations can be used to describe functions.
Some famous ones include
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - f(x) = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} - f(x) = 0$$
The iterated running xor working on a sequence of numbers $\{x_0,\cdots,x_N\}$ on $\mathbb Z_2$ :
$$\mathcal{X}\{x\}_{k} = x_{k} \oplus x_{k-1}$$
carries some of similar properties as the differential operator with perhaps the most obvious one: constants are taken to $0$. A string of $x_{k_1}=x_{k_1+1}=\cdots=x_{k_2}$ will give $\mathcal{X}\{x\}_{k} = 0$ for all $k\in\{k_1+1,k_2\}$.
We can obviously model or represent (families of) continuous functions with differential equations.
Now to my question : how can we do the same with iterated xor operations?

"xor" corresponds to addition  over the binary field $\mathbb F_2$. I suppose a natural generalization of differential equations in this context might be recurrence equations for sequences in $\mathbb F_2$.   For example, the linear
equation
$$ x_{n+1} = x_{n} + x_{n-5}$$
with initial conditions $x_0 = 1$, $x_1 = \ldots = x_5 = 0$
produces an interesting sequence with period $63$.

Yes, wonderful! Thank you Robert. Something akin to this is precisely what I had in mind. For my toy examples of thresholded sine waves this can reduce the number of 1 bits very closely to what I believe would be the theoretically optimal.
